# Effective pairwise comparisons for group ranking?

Tags: paired-data, ranking, group-differences

Suppose I have a list of items(~3500 in number) and I want to do a group based ranking into 4-5 groups. I can get pairwise comparisons between the elements but I want to choose the items to compare in each pairwise comparisons in some intelligent manner. I am looking for ways to do this and get reliable data.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I should go about doing this? Are there standard algorithms people follow for picking items to compare? I have been trying to find things but most methods I find on the internet talk about how to rank after getting pairwise data but I want to know how to get effective pairwise data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by group ranking? Group/rank in what way? Are you trying to cluster your data?

Comment: It would help if you told what items these are, because it seems to me like this could be some gene or protein expression data am I wrong ? Why 4-5 groups ?

Comment: Hi, I am looking to cluster the data. These items are more subjective things like 'comments' with a particular emotion or tone, etc.